# How to separate and run the code part of an Ipython notebook?

Tags: web-services, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-console

I have an IPython file. I want to take all the code-parts of the Ipython file and run it separately to display all plots and figures.(All the code-part is refering to the fact that a ipython file has both markdown and code snippets and I want only code part.) How can this be done? 
I have tried to take the code and paste it in jupyter console but it won't still display images. For example I have

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image('http://jakevdp.github.com/figures/mpl_version.png')
```

It returns < IPython.core.display.Image object > but not the actual image. How do I get to display the actual image? Finally, I want to implement this as a web service so that users can upload .ipynb files and get all the output plots of the python codes as output.

Comment: Are you asking for a programatic way to run the code-cells of a notebook, or how to display images? These are separate questions.

Comment: In some cells, the above code can be present which on running should display the particular image. So, basically I need to display images on running the code above .